# Delete initial (matching) pattern from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have the following vector of character strings:

```
v<-c("RT @name1: hello world", "Hi guys, how are you?", "Hello RT I have no text", "RT @name2: Hello!")
```

I would like to delete only those `RT` that are positioned at the beginning of strings and store the results in another vector, e.g., `w`:

```
> w
 "@name1: hello world"    "Hi guys, how are you?"     "Hello RT I have no text"     "@name2: Hello!"
```

Maybe I could use function `str_extract_all` from the package `stringr`, but I can't apply it to my problem.

Comment: `sub("^RT\\s?", "", v)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gsub` and the 'anchor' `^`, which signifies the beginning of a string:

```
w <- gsub("^RT\\s", "", v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<-  str_replace(v,"^RT","")
```

Comment: just put carat symbol at the begnning of regex pattern

Comment: vector name is missing